# Wrong XML file encoding (æ,ø,å letters) - how to encode product feeds properly

Tags: php, xml, character-encoding

I am making a WordPress plugin that should load 2 types of XML files (product feed files), then locate the stock status field, and then retain all in-stock products and return a list of in-stock product URLs from these XML product feeds.

I have hardcoded all the possible in-stock values the stock status field can take, and until now, these values have only been "instock", "in stock", "yes" and values over 0. But in a new product feed I just added, the in-stock value is "På lager". And I thought that I could just add this new value to my function (in the part where i hardcode the values), but that does not work.

I have tried everything, but nothing helps... I have also tried to echo the values, and see the values my plugin outputs (which is "PÃ¥ lager"), but I am not able to decode it as 'på lager'.

I don't know if it has something to do with the encoding of the XML or something completely different. I really hope someone can help me out here...

I have attached my function code, and i have attached an example of the new product feed.

Function:

```
function fetch_and_parse_product_feed_with_xmlreader($feed_entry) {
    $reader = new XMLReader();
    // Access the 'url' key from the feed entry
    if (!$reader->open($feed_entry['url'])) {
        echo "<p>Failed to open feed: " . esc_url($feed_entry['url']) . "</p>";
        return array();
    }

    $in_stock_products = array();
    while ($reader->read()) {
        if ($reader->nodeType == XMLReader::ELEMENT) {
            if ($reader->localName == 'produkt') {
                // Handling for Feed type 1
                $productXml = $reader->readOuterXML();
                $product = simplexml_load_string($productXml);
                $stock_status = strtolower((string)$product->lagerantal);
                if ($stock_status === 'instock' || $stock_status === 'in stock' || intval($stock_status) > 0 || $stock_status === 'yes' || $stock_status === 'på lager') {
                    $processed_url = process_url_for_comparison((string)$product->vareurl);
                    $in_stock_products[] = $processed_url;
                }
            } elseif ($reader->localName == 'product') {
                // Handling for Feed type 2
                $productXml = $reader->readOuterXML();
                $product = simplexml_load_string($productXml);
                $stock_status = strtolower((string)$product->Instock);
                if ($stock_status === 'instock' || $stock_status === 'in stock' || intval($stock_status) > 0 || $stock_status === 'yes') {
                    $processed_url = process_url_for_comparison((string)$product->TrackingUrl);
                    $in_stock_products[] = $processed_url;
                }
            }
        }
    }

    $reader->close();
    return $in_stock_products;
}
```

XML product feed:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="iso-8859-1"?>
<produkter>
<produkt>
<forhandler>Cykelpartner</forhandler>
<kategorinavn>Rullebremser &amp; fodbremser</kategorinavn>
<brand>Shimano</brand>
<produktnavn>Shimano Nexus - Skrue og møtrik for bremsewire ved rullebremser bag - BR-IM45-R</produktnavn>
<produktid>4524667690467</produktid>
<ean>4524667690467</ean>
<beskrivelse>Original øjebolt med møtrik der anvendes til fastgørelse af bremsewiren på en Shimano Nexus rullebremse i bag model BR-I...</beskrivelse>
<nypris>24.00</nypris>
<glpris>24.00</glpris>
<fragtomk>45</fragtomk>
<lagerantal>På lager</lagerantal>
<leveringstid>1-3 dage</leveringstid>
<size></size>
<color></color>
</produkt>
<produkt>
<forhandler>Cykelpartner</forhandler>
<kategorinavn>Bremsegreb</kategorinavn>
<brand>Shimano</brand>
<produktnavn>Shimano GRX - STI greb Højre - ST-RX820 - Til 12 gears kassetter - Hydraulisk</produktnavn>
<produktid>4550170173432</produktid>
<ean>4550170173432</ean>
<beskrivelse>Dette STI skifte- og bremsegreb fra Shimanos GRX gravel 12 gears serie, tilhører den kvalitetsmæssige top. Grebet er model ST-RX820, o...</beskrivelse>
<nypris>2349.00</nypris>
<glpris>2349.00</glpris>
<fragtomk>0</fragtomk>
<lagerantal>Ikke på lager</lagerantal>
<leveringstid>Ukendt leveringstid</leveringstid>
<size></size>
<color></color>
<billedurl>https://resources.chainbox.io/5/cykelpartner/public/pim/bb10bd81-d2af-401d-a50c-ed5f3adcc159/istrx820rbi_a_default.jpg</billedurl>
</produkt>
</produkter>
```

So basically, i want the function to solely return the URL for the first product in the product feed (because the first product has the in-stock value "På lager" while the second product has the out-of-stock value "Ikke på lager".

I have tried debugging by echoing the initial stock status value.

Comment: Can you upload your XML file somewhere?

Comment: Oh, that feed weighs 23 MB, so I see now why you used XMLReader. In which encoding is your PHP script?

Comment: @Olivier I edit my PHP file directly from cPanel editor. And every time i open the PHP file, it opens in the encoding euc-kr. But then i always make sure to re-open the PHP file in UTF-8 encoding and then save the file, because I have heard that encoding is better. It just confuses me that it opens in euc-kr everytime even though i always reopen in UTF-8 and then save the file (and I then assume the file is saved in UTF-8).

Comment: You should download the script and check the encoding.

Comment: @Olivier I just copy/pasted all the code into a new php file and saved that in visual studio code with encoding UTF-8. The function still doesn't find 'På lager'

Comment: Do you mean you uploaded a new script?

Comment: Yes. I replaced the old PHP script with a new that is saved using Visual studio in UTF-8 encoding.

Comment: I can try send you the script if you like, but I must be able to send you a message then.

Comment: It should work. What does `echo strlen('På lager');` show?

Comment: "På" rendered as "PÃ¥" indicates UTF-8 misinterpreted as ISO 8859-1, 
see [mojibake](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mojibake#Other_Western_European_languages)
(end of section).

Comment: @Olivier just tried to add it ´´´echo strlen('På lager')´´´ but that just returns alot of 9's.

Comment: @urznow okay, so what can I do to solve the misinterpretation?

Comment: Which version of PHP are you using?

Comment: @KasperToftBraun: The XML product feed is encoded as ISO-8859-1, I take it the script is UTF-8. It seems to me that one must be modified.

Comment: @urznow When XMLReader reads the file, it converts it to UTF-8 (as stated [here](https://www.php.net/manual/en/intro.xmlreader.php)).

Comment: my phpinfo.php file says it's: PHP version: 8.1.27

Comment: @KasperToftBraun: I think perhaps the XML product feed is in fact encoded as UTF-8 but declares itself as ISO-8859-1. Try changing "iso-8859-1" to "UTF-8"  in the XML declaration.

Comment: @urznow The XML file is fine. It turns out there is an issue with the `XMLReader` parser (see my answer).

Comment: @Olivier: Good catch! If it's a known issue, a link would be appreciated.

Comment: Glad it finally works! Yes, you should always use a temporary file. Your code is fine.

Comment: @Olivier i am facing extremely large memory usage by having to download the temporary files. Isn't there a way to make this work when streaming the XML files?

Comment: `stream_copy_to_stream()` does not load the whole file in memory. It can process arbitrarily large files.

Comment: @Olivier but will that be able to read special characters like æ, ø, and å?

Comment: I don't understand the question. `stream_copy_to_stream()` is what I used in my answer.

Comment: Yes, but i get a 503 server error when using the stream_copy_to_stream approach. That approach is too resource intensive. Look at my code here: https://sharemycode.fr/8yz

Answer (score 2):

After some tests, I could reproduce this strange issue. It occurs on PHP versions starting from 8.1 when parsing directly from HTTP.

As a workaround, download the feed to a local temp file:

```php
$file = tempnam('.', 'feed');
$local = fopen($file, 'w');
$remote = fopen('https://...', 'r');
stream_copy_to_stream($remote, $local);
fclose($local);
fclose($remote);

$nb = 0;
$reader = new XMLReader();
$reader->open($file);
while ($reader->read()) {
    if ($reader->nodeType == XMLReader::ELEMENT) {
        if ($reader->localName == 'produkt') {
            $productXml = $reader->readOuterXML();
            $product = simplexml_load_string($productXml);
            $stock_status = strtolower((string)$product->lagerantal);
            if ($stock_status === 'på lager')
                $nb++;
        }
    }
}
$reader->close();
echo "På lager found: $nb";

unlink($file);
```

Output:

```
På lager found: 22026
```

Remark: I didn't do any error checking in the download part, I will let you do it properly.

Comment: Perfect answer. Can i get you to hide the feed URL for privacy reasons?

Comment: Check the content type http header. It might be the wrong content type or encoding (charset).